# Launching a Daemon from Python, then detaching the Parent from the Child

Tags: python

I'm running a daemon on a remote machine: **mydaemon**. This daemon should be persistently running at all times.

When I'm running a job on my remote machine, it also launches a lightweight python server process, **my_remote_server.py**.

One of the commands I can send to **my_remote_server.py** is to restart **mydaemon**, which I'm trying to do like this:

```
os.system("killall mydaemon")
subprocess.Popen(["mydaemon"], stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

When my job ends, **my_remote_server.py** is supposed to terminate, but **mydaemon** should keep running. However I see **my_remote_server.py** stuck as a zombie process (This is causing the system to not see my job as terminated)

```
  820 root            Z   [my_remote_serve]
  834 root        552 S   /usr/sbin/telnetd -l /bin/sh 
  835 root        836 S   /bin/sh 
  844 root        672 S   mydaemon
```

I want to detach Parent (**my_remote_server.py**) from the child (**mydaemon**), but I can't figure out how.

--
My python version is 2.5.4

### edit:

I think I understand daemonization a bit better now, but I'm still having some trouble getting the daemon to separate

I'm leaving out the error handling here for brevity

```
os.system("killall mydaemon")

if(os.fork() > 0):
    return True # my_remote_server.py returns to handle additional commands

os.setsid()
if(os.fork() > 0):
    exit(0) # first child exits after becoming session leader

os.execlp("mydaemon") # have the second child run as the daemon
```

This is my ps list before I call the restart_mydaemon function

```
252 root        672 S   mydaemon
286 root       4552 S   /usr/bin/python my_remote_server.py
```

This is after restart_mydaemon, first child is zombied (shouldn't it be gone?)

```
286 root       4552 S   /usr/bin/python my_remote_server.py
300 root            Z   [my_remote_serve]
304 root        672 S   [mydaemon]
```

This is when the job terminates (my_remote_server.py should have exited, but it's a zombie, however, the first child has exited now at this point)

```
286 root            Z   [my_remote_serve]
304 root       1012 S   [mydaemon]
```

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of Python?

Comment: Each of the remote machines are using an Intel IXP420 (network ARM processor) from 2004. New custom machines are being designed with a new arch soon, so until then we're sticking with what we have.

Answer (score 1):

Turning a process into a daemon is a multi-step process.  Part of your problem is that your parent process is not waiting for child termination correctly (read about wait/waitpid),

- Your process must close any open file descriptors (stdin, stdout, stderr)
- Your process needs to (change directory, set umask, whatever you want/need)
- You must fork a process
- That process must become a process group leader
- You must fork again, to fully detach from the (grand)parent

  ```
  try:
      #free parent, detach from process group
      pid = os.fork()
      if( pid>0 ):
          exit(0) #parent exits
  except OSError, e:
      raise Exception("%s [%d]" % (e.strerror, e.errno))
  #become session leader, process group leader, detach from controlling terminal
  os.setsid()
  try:
      #prevent zombie process, make init cleanup
      pid = os.fork()
      if( pid>0 ):
          exit(0) #parent exits
  except OSError, e:
      raise Exception("%s [%d]" % (e.strerror, e.errno))
  #change directories, close stdin/out/err, etc
  os.chdir(MYDIR)
  os.umask(MYMASK)
  #close files (including stdin, stdout, stderr)
  #(re)open new stdin/stdout, if desired
  ```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to handle opening and closing stdin/out/err, and am I able to to it after the first fork, because my_remote_server.py has it's stdin/out/err harnessed to a Perl script through IPC::Run (from CPAN), and I don't want to mess with that while the Python is running.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for reference/good explanation of how daemonization works:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731/

Overall this is pretty non-trivial, I would try using the python-daemon library or similar library:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call sub process to do this. Sub process imo should only be used to run a command that you cant import.

So in this case your my_remote_server.py could import the mydaemon and run it.

You have 2 ways of doing this. You could make my_remote_server the parent and mydaemon the child. Or have a new script that is the parent and spawns 2 children(mydaemon, my_remote_server).

For example. Below I create a child process. Global scope since i need to access it in the HTTP handler of tornado. I set up the Web Server. Start the Child process and then start the web server. When the endpoint is hit the handler runs and the child process is pulled from the global scope. We terminate the child process and print. You could add more endpoint to tornado to start the child again or stop and then restart it.

**remote.py:**

```
import multiprocessing
import deamon
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

child_pro = multiprocessing.Process(target=deamon.run_deamon)
child_pro.daemon = True


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        global child_pro
        child_pro = child_pro  # type: multiprocessing.Process
        child_pro.terminate()
        print ("Child killed")


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    global child_pro
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    child_pro.start()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

**deamon.py:**

```
import time


def run_deamon():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        print ('child alive')
```